# Open Graph Action translations... import an XML with translations?

Tags: internationalization, translation, facebook-opengraph

I've looked through the docs and admin panel and don't see a way to "import translations."

Do I really need to enter them by hand via the Bulk UI?

We have 400 strings x 26 languages, it'd be great if I can import translations in XML back into the system... one file per locale.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have the same question here. We have more apps which use the same actions and got 256 strings. If anyone knows how import translation files from another app it would be very helpful.

Comment: Any news for this question ?